# FFMPEG - How to Merge Three Files - Only Middle One Has Audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I have three videos that I want to merge into single one.

1. Intro video (mp4) - 3 seconds - No Audio
2. Main video (mp4) - 1 minute - With Audio
3. End video (mp4) - 3 seconds - No Audio

When I use ffmpeg, using this command.

`ffmpeg -f concat -i merge.txt -c copy output.mp4`

It does not have any audio for the output.

```
Merge.txt
file 'intro.mp4'
file 'main.mp4'
file 'end.mp4'
```

I understand that I need to use `-filter_complex` with some concat function for audio/video stream. I just can't figure it out.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do any filtering, or reencoding if all inputs have been encoded using the same parameters.

You first extract the audio stream from your **main** input, then merge the three video inputs whilst copying  the audio stream with a 3 second offset.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -c:a copy audio.aac
ffmpeg -f concat -i merge.txt -itsoffset 3 -i audio.aac -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
del audio.aac
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it. It worked in that it was able to merge them. But the length of the video messed up and the sync was off. Main video was about 4 minutes long. But the output video is now 8 minutes long, and the audio stopped in the middle, also the last video did not merge at the end. Not sure what is going on :) BTW, it also had this warning while converting. `Non-monotonic DTS in output stream`

Comment: Strange, this works for me. I did get some Non-monotonic DTS warnings with some TS files I tested, but even they had no playback issues. MKV and MP4's were fine. I did test with content that was created with identical encoding settings/parameters, could that be your issue ?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the frame rate of one of the videos was different, so I had to fix it first and then it worked, `ffmpeg -y -r 30 -i Main.mp4 mainFix.mp4`

Comment: Concatenation without reencoding relies on inputs that not only require similar settings, fps, scale etc, but the parameters used to encode, or create the inputs must also be identical. There is some tolerance with this rule, but no guarantees.